# please help identify this bmx brand logo!

Tags: frames, bmx

having trouble identifying this logo found on my Bmx frame- any ideas?

Many thanks[image]

Comment: Is there no text anywhere on the bike's frame ?

Comment: Great badge. I love these bmx logos.

Comment: Anything unusual about the frame design? Photo of the full frame/bike?